# Unexpected results when multiplying unitless values in SASS

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have stumbled across a strange issue while using SASS to create a small CSS framework for a unique project I'm working on.

Without going into unnecessary detail, I'm creating a series of 10 `z-index` classes using a `@for` loop. Each `z-index` value should be a multiple of 10 starting with the first index.

```
/* Loop from 1 to 10, creating 10 z-index classes */
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
    .z#{$i} { z-index: ($i * 10) }
}

/* This SHOULD output... */
.z1 { z-index: 10 }
.z2 { z-index: 20 }
.z3 { z-index: 30 }
.z4 { z-index: 40 }
.z5 { z-index: 50 }
.z6 { z-index: 60 }
.z7 { z-index: 70 }
.z8 { z-index: 80 }
.z9 { z-index: 90 }
.z10 { z-index: 100 }
```

**The Problem:** It doesn't output the values I'm expecting. Instead I'm getting values of `1, 2, 3, etc` where I should be getting values of `10, 20, 30, etc`.

**How to make it fail**
I can multiply two unitless values and get the result I expect with `line-height`. But if I do it for `z-index` I get strange results. Here are some other examples of how I made this fail. I included values for `font-size` and `line-height` and they turn out the way I would expect.

```
.example-1 {
    font-size: (16px * 1.5); // outputs 24px
    line-height: (1 * 1.5);  // outputs 1.5
    z-index: (10 * 10);      // should output 100, but it outputs 5
}

.example-2 {
    z-index: (10 * 10);      // outputs 5 (wrong)
    z-index: (10 / 10);      // outputs 1
    z-index: (10 + 10);      // outputs 2 (wrong)
    z-index: (10 - 10);      // outputs 0
}
```

I feel crazy. Has anyone else run into this issue?

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**.

Apparently, the `gulp-cssnano` plugin, which minifies the CSS as part of my build process, is causing this to happen. By default, `gulp-cssnano` will rebase your z-index values, which is NOT cool and probably shouldn't be cool to anyone else either. Regardless, this was neatly fixed by passing in the option `{ zindex: false }` to the call to `gulp-cssnano`.

```
.pipe( cssnano({ zindex: false }) );
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with your compilation process. When I run your code and your example tests inside of a codepen, the compiled output is what you expect.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the compilation process as well. I'm using `gulp-sass`, `gulp-autoprefixer` and `gulp-cssnano` to handle compiling, vendor prefixes and minification. I'm going to try removing these dependencies and see if I get different results.

Comment: It works fine in Codepen (click 'View Compiled CSS' in the SCSS window dropdown) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEZXxp - perhaps it's something to do with your compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `gulp-cssnano` is causing the issue through one of it's optimizations.

From what I can see `cssnano` has an optimization for `z-index` and is labeled *"unsafe."* You can disable various optimizations or configure them with an options object in gulp. Try something along these lines:

```js
.pipe( 
    nano( {
        zindex: false
    } )
)
```

Comment: Oh my mistake, I had that correct in my original code but re-typed it without the `#` in my example. I updated the original question with this fixed.

Comment: I'm using `gulp-sass` to compile SASS into CSS and I'm also using `gulp-autoprefixer` to inject vendor prefixes and `gulp-cssnano` for minification.

Comment: `gulp-cssnano` has been narrowed down as the reason for the problem. However, I don't know how to fix it or work around it at the moment.

Comment: Success!!! Thank you! I had no idea that `cssnano` even gave a shit about my z-indexes... oh well.

Comment: I will update my answer to reflect comments and remove old comments.